# Anime where a male main character recovers some powers when he recovers memories

Tags: story-identification, anime

The male main character recovers his power of magician and swordsman when he recovers his memories.

Comment: This is incredibly brief and likely to match quite a few anime. Can you remember anything else about this else this is likely to end up closed? When did you watch it? Was it episodic or a film? Can you remember what channel if on TV? How did he lose his memories? How does recovering them make him regain powers? What is the plot, or anything smaller that happens? If you remember anything else you should [edit] those details into the question.

Comment: Just like Corwin of Amber, but not anime =)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is *[Seiken Tsukai no World Break](https://myanimelist.net/anime/22663/Seiken_Tsukai_no_World_Break)* (AKA *World Break: Aria of Curse for a Holy Swordsman*).

[image]

The main character recovers memories -- and consequently skills/powers -- from two past lives; one where he was a swordsman, and another where he was a magician.

> Seiken Tsukai no World Break takes place at Akane Private Academy where **students who possess memories of their previous lives are being trained to use Ancestral Arts so that they can serve as defenders against monsters**, called Metaphysicals, who randomly attack. Known as saviors, the students are broken up into two categories: the kurogane who are able to use their prana to summon offensive weapons and the kuroma who are able to use magic.
>
> The story begins six months prior to the major climax of the series during the opening ceremonies on the first day of the school year. After the ceremony is over, the main character, **Moroha Haimura, meets a girl named Satsuki Ranjou who reveals that she was Moroha's little sister in a past life where Moroha was a heroic prince capable of slaying entire armies with his sword skills. Soon afterwards he meets another girl, Shizuno Urushibara, who eventually reveals that she also knew Moroha in an entirely different past life where he was a dark lord capable of using destructive magic** but saved her from a life of slavery. Can those whose minds live in both the present and the past truly reach a bright future? Delve into the complex world of Seiken Tsukai no World Break to find out!

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting buttons.

Comment: It is fine to close a story id question you know? In fact it is preferable in most cases where there is very little information. I've seen you almost exclusively leave story id questions open in the queues, so please be aware that it is an option to close them and it's not a bad thing to do so, the opposite in fact in some cases.

Comment: @Is it preferable to close such questions even when correct answers can be provided in relatively short order?

Comment: You, yourself, state _"One possibility"_. With many potential matches and little to no detail in the question you should usually defer to voting to close the question. There are lots of times you could probably find an answer the fits the criteria but if it's so generic that many would fit, it's a lot better to vote to close and encourage the OP to add more details.

Comment: I have a fairly high level of confidence about this answer; it's a perfect match, and while there may be other perfect matches, I don't know that for a fact. I understand the criticism of sparsely-worded questions like this, but my instinct is to allow a grace period of perhaps a day or so to see if they can be answered or not, rather than closing them within an hour or two. It seems premature to conclude that a question can't be answered without allowing a reasonable amount of time for an answer to be submitted and accepted.

Comment: Question closure isn't a bad thing, it's a signal to the OP to improve their question. Sometimes providing answers can make the OP not want to because they won't see the need, since they already have answer/s, and make things worse. I understand the premise of a grace period but it doesn't really work that way, if something should be closed, it should be closed no matter the time. That said I may wait to cast the first close vote to see if the OP responds with a comment or edit but if it's already in the queue it's best to close if it needs closing.

Comment: It might help if you think of the closure as the grace period, closure is meant to be a temporary state before either an edit so it's suitable for reopening or deletion if no further edits/clarifications are made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119533/discussion-between-logicdictates-and-thelethalcarrot).